# How to point android build system at different android.jar file

Tags: android, ant, jar, build, build.xml

I have created an "extended" android.jar file that includes classes that are only known internal to the Android system using [this guide](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/). In the guide, the author suggests creating a new platform in android-sdk-linux/platforms/ to build against that includes the extended android.jar file.

The problem I have with this is that I want to be able to keep this file in version control as part of the build system (and I would rather not keep the entire Android SDK in version control). So what I would like to do is to simply keep the extended android.jar in version control with my app, and then at build time, have my build system point to the extended android.jar instead of the one kept in android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-/. Is this possible, and if so, what's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Is adding a build system step that copies the jar from wherever you put it in source control to that special platform folder an option?

Comment: That would certainly work, but I'd prefer not to have to add a special platform directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is as follows:

In the build.xml file for your app, there should be a line that looks something like this:

```
<import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />
```

This allows you to import a file in your build that enables you to customize build rules. You may or may not have this file, depending on if you've customized your build already.

To point the build at your custom android.jar file, you can make the custom_rules.xml file look something like this (or just add the line containing the classpath if you already have created a custom_rules.xml file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="custom_rules" default="debug">
    <property name="java.compiler.classpath" value="custom_libs/android.jar" />
</project>
```

Obviously the value you enter for the classpath depends on your build system. I simply added a "custom_libs" directory next to the custom_rules.xml file, and placed my custom android.jar in there.